# Подгрузка html в div

Tags: javascript, html

Есть div и кнопка, по нажатию необходимо подгрузить в этот блок html страницу:

html:

```
<div>
<div id = "showDiv" width = "100px" height = "400px" >
  Отображение страницы
</div>
<button id = "buttonWinter">Зима</button>
<button id = "buttonSpring">Весна</button>
<button id = "buttonSummer">Лето</button>
<button id = "buttonAutumn">Осень</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   var buttonWinter = document.getElementById('buttonWinter');
   buttonWinter.addEventListener('click',ShowWinter);
   function ShowWinter(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   $('#showDiv').on('../html/winter.html');
   }
```

Не подгружается почему?

Comment: метод load это для версией jquery ниже 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод *$().on()* принимает как минимум два аргумента (из документации jquery): **events** и **handler**.
И насколько мне известно, нельзя загрузить этим методом значения в html.

Воспользуйтесь методом *$().load('path_to');*

```
var buttonWinter = document.getElementById('buttonWinter'); 
buttonWinter.addEventListener('click',ShowWinter);
   function ShowWinter(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('#showDiv').load('../html/winter.html');
   }
```

Или воспользоваться *ajax'ом*.

Comment: метод load это для версией jquery ниже 3, а у меня 3.1

Comment: @bsuart2017 он и в 3+ версии отлично работает, или у вас есть какие-то особые причины его не использовать?

Comment: к сожалению, сталкивался с тем, что не совсем отлично работает в 3+

Comment: @bsuart2017, это очень странно, возможно там было что-то не так с Вашим кодом?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно когда у тебя срабатывает js, разметка еще не погрузилась, оберни код в:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   //Оберни код
});
```

либо покажи полностью, если это не все